# dbx debugger able to pass command line parameters on dbx startup?

Tags: debugging, dbx

I use both GDB and DBX depending on the platform I'm debugging.  I need to debug a tool where there are 20 command line parameters that need to be passed.  GDB has an option where you can pass these parameters upon gdb startup:

gdb  --args    ...

I am looking for a similar way to do this in DBX.  I'm hoping to save time rather than cutting and pasting all the time.  I read parts of the manual, and I couldn't see a way to do this.

Comment: Huh. Haven't thought about DBX in 30 years. Since GDB runs on almost everything, any chance you can get/config/make/install?

Comment: No, we still have to live with SunStudio for a while, unless management here decides to transition Sun's compiler toward GDB.

Comment: You could also put the arguments along with runargs into an external file and use: dbx -c ". external-file.ksh"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can execute *runargs* command on startup

```
dbx -c "runargs --all --your --flags" a.out
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  There is a caveat that your command line args must be less than 250 or 255 characters.  This same limitation exists when you try to cut and paste command line args when using the "run" command.

Comment: If you have a management insisting on using Sun Studio, then you probably have a support contact with Oracle? Just ask them to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run app with name `yourApp` using dbx for debugging. For example:
`yourApp param1 param2`

You can do it by using command `run` from `dbx`:

```
> dbx yourApp
Type 'help' for help.
reading symbolic information ...
(dbx) run param1 param2
      //some output made by yourApp
(dbx)
```